# How does Caine stabbing John make them even if it's not personal?

Tags: plot-explanation, john-wick-chapter-4

John prevented Chidi from killing Mr. Nobody's dog during their confrontation.
This caused Mr. Nobody to abandon his pursuit of John. After Caine and Mr. Nobody
assisted John in fighting off several assassins, including Chidi, who was killed by
Mr. Nobody, on the Rue Foyatier, Caine stabbed John Wick in the hand:

> Caine: Nothing personal, John.
>
> John Wick: **We're even now**.
>
> Then they reached Sacré-Cœur just in time for the duel.

How does Caine stabbing John make them even if it's not personal?

Comment: They were friends, doing what they thought should be done.